# Why does calling vent:stop() in CBEffects result in all timers being cancelled?

Tags: timer, lua, coronasdk, cancellation, particle-system

Is anyone here familiar with this open-source particle emitter CBEffects? It's pretty great and generally straightforward but somehow whenever I call vent:stop(), which behind the scenes cancels the emitter timer, all timers get cancelled. Did anyone experience incidents similar to that? I checked the source code and it's definitely cancelling the right timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Never mind. I just found out, that it was due to an updated timer library.